# How to parse mpeg2ts in browser?

Tags: javascript, video, video-streaming, html5-video

I would like to make a stream with epg data. I have only mpeg2ts video stream. How to parse mpeg2ts stream in  browser?
Maybe you know some libs that can do this?

Comment: did you manage to find a way for a mpeg 2 ts stream parsing in browser? any clue?

Comment: Sorry for late. it`s impossible, Exist only one way to make this. You have to convert the stream to his or mpeg4, you can use ffmpeg for it,

Comment: nope :) there is another way, you could write own demuxer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will get you most of the way there: https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js/

HLS is for the most part a fragmented MPEG2 Transport Stream.